# How can I add arrows onto gnuplot contour plot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, arrows, tikz-arrows, gnuplot

I have a contour plot for a doublet flow, but I'm trying to add arrows onto the contour plots.

```
 \begin{axis}[ xshift=8cm,
    ticks = none,
    view={0}{90},
    xmin = -1, ymin = -3,
    xmax = 5, ymax= 3,
    axis background/.style={fill=white} ]

       \addplot3 [ samples=101,smooth,  contour gnuplot={levels={-2.5,-1.75,-1,-0.75,-0.5,-0.4,0,0.4,0.5,0.75,1,1.75,2.5}, draw color = black, labels=false, }] {0-y/((x-2)^2 + y^2)};
        \addplot3 [ samples=101,smooth, contour gnuplot={levels={-2.5,-1.75,-1,-0.75,-0.5,-0.4,0,0.4,0.5,0.75,1,1.75,2.5}, draw color = red, labels=false}] {(x-2)/((x-2)^2 + y^2)};


\end{axis}
```

I have tried using decorate but it doesn't work. Here is an example of what it should look like with the red arrows.

[image]

Comment: As it seems this is not doable in an easy way. At least all my attempts to add the arrows sooner or later ended in a "dimension too large" error ...